# TypeScript constructor overload return different types

Tags: typescript

I have a constructor function that should return a different type based on a param.

```
interface B {
    hello(): string;
}

class Foo {  
    constructor(withB: boolean): Foo & B;
    constructor();
    constructor(withB?: boolean) {
        if (withB) {
            Object.assign(this, { hello() {}})
        }
    }
}

const foo1 = new Foo();
const foo3 = new Foo(true);
```

But It's not working. How can I do it?

Comment: The point of a constructor is to return the type of the class it is the constructor for. I would recommend using a static method. Your problem also might lend itself to [mixins](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html) depending on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't define such a class directly. You can define your regular class and rename it to `FooImpl` and declare a constant that represent the constructor with the dirrent overloads and assign the `FooImpl` to it:

```
interface B {
    hello(): string;
}

class FooImpl { 
    constructor(withB?: boolean) {
        if (withB) {
            Object.assign(this, { hello() {}})
        }
    }
}

const Foo : {
    new(withB: boolean): FooImpl & B;
    new() : FooImpl;
}= FooImpl as any;


const foo1 = new Foo(); // FooImpl
const foo3 = new Foo(true); // FooImpl & B
```

If your interface only has methods, you might also get away with generics and specifying the `this` parameter on the interface methods, restricting their visibility to only certain parameters for the type:

```
interface B {
    hello(): string;
}

class Foo<T=void> {
    private withB: T;  
    constructor(withB: T) ;
    constructor();
    constructor(withB?: boolean) {
    }
    hello(this: Foo<boolean>): string {
        return "";
    }
}


const foo1 = new Foo();
foo1.hello() // Invalid
const foo3 = new Foo(true);
foo3.hello() // Valid
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if I need to extend Foo? Will it still work?

Comment: I'm interested in your last approach, but I didn't get it. How the hello method is valid when you pass true?

Comment: As to your first point I don't know and can't test right now, I'll get back to you on this, but I expect you need to to the same thing for derived types. The second approach is predicated on the fact that you can specify what type the this parameter need to have. If you have a this that is only valid for certain generic parameter the method will not be callable if other generic parameters are specified

Comment: Are there any updates on this or is this answer still the good one ?

Comment: @Strebler the first approach still works, the second approach works but is less ideal since they stopped filtering members by `this` parameter. There are no new language features that would make this easier to implement.